# How to make a react component receive updates from the back-end?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm working on an application that multiple users can collaborate on at the same time. If a user make changes to the database, how do I update the component for other users? Do I need to make a function that runs every minute for example and check to see if the database has changed and then apply those changes, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) to get live updates from the backend. LongPolling is also possible but less efficient.

The Websocket implementation depends on what technology you are using on the backend, if you are using NodeJS, check out this [link - WebSockets/ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws)
Otherwise just google WebSockets + technology term

Comment: Its not a lack of code that is the problem, rather it is that the question as phrased is too broad.

Comment: Thank you, Bruno and code11, for your help. Websocket is exactly what I was looking for. All the best to you.